# Organizar el canvas con z-index

Tags: javascript, canvas

Soy un novato experimentado en HTML pero soy nuevo en trabajar con canvas tengo el problema de que tengo que intentar que la imagen que fue puesta dentro del canvas tengo que ponerla encima del dibujo echo por JS en el mismo canvas e intentado con cambiar el orden en como se ejecutan pero no resulta en ningún cambio. Recuerdo haber visto algo como z-index para organizar los elementos dibujados pero no lo encuentro. Acepto también cualquier otra alternativa.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "imagen.png";
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 20, 20);
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 50, 5, 90, 60, 110);
  grd.addColorStop(1, "darkcyan");
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
}
```

```css
.elemento {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.elemento:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="20px" heigth="20px" class="elemento"></canvas>

<!--El canvas es un 20 * 20 pero no se ejecuta bien -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer que la imagen aparezca encima del rectángulo hay que utilizar `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";` antes de rellenar el rectángulo. Esto dice que la imagen existente (*destination*) aparece encima de la nueva imagen (*source*).

Por favor lea acerca de [combinar trazados con globalCompositeOperation](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/globalCompositeOperation.php) en canvas.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  //especifica la anchura y la altura del canvas
  c.width=20;
  c.height=20;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "imagen.png";
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 20, 20);
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 50, 5, 90, 60, 110);
  grd.addColorStop(1, "darkcyan");
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  
  
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  
  
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
```

```css
.elemento {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.elemento:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="elemento"></canvas>

<!--El canvas es un 20 * 20 pero no se ejecuta bien -->
```

También puedes dibujar primero el rectángulo y solo después dibujar la imagen